# Random number generator help needed

Tags: c++, function, random

I am using a random number generator in my code to randomly select if a process fails or not. I am trying to use a very large range of numbers to make the fail rate very low but so far it keeps coming up true every time. how do i fix this?

```
//Random number generator
int crash_chance(double Dis) {
int chance;
chance = 0;
while (chance < (Dis/100), chance++){

    int x = rand() % 1000000000000 + 1; //Generate an integer between 1 and 1000000000000
    return x;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Even when I fix that code to move the return outside of the loop, it still indicates a crash.

I'll add the code that calls the function, as requested.

```
rand = crash_chance(D);
bool crash;
if (rand = 1){ crash = true; };
if (rand != 1){ crash = false; };
```

**EDIT 2 **
so the code below cannot be fixed?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

//the three functions below ask the user for the required input.
double altitude(){
double alti;
cout << "Please input the change in altitude in meters:";
cin >> alti;
return alti;
}

double RoC()
{
double climbR;
cout << "Please input climb rate in m/s:";
cin >> climbR;


return climbR;
}

double speed(){
double v;
cout << "Please input your current speed over ground in m/s" << endl;
cin >> v;
return v;
}

//  Gives you the time it will take to reach desired altitude
double time(double A, double R){
double t;
t = A / R;
return t;
}

//Distance travelled horizontally in given time
double distancetravelled(double Veloc, double Time){

double D;
D = Veloc*Time;

return D;
}


//This will convert time to days, hours, minutes, and seconds.
vector<double> converted_time(double input_seconds){
int hours;
int minutes;
double seconds;
hours = (input_seconds / 60) / 60;
input_seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
minutes = (input_seconds / 60);
input_seconds -= minutes * 60;
seconds = input_seconds;
//puts values into a vector
vector<double>times(4);
times[0] = hours;
times[1] = minutes;
times[2] = seconds;

return times;


}

//prints the time in hours,minutes,seconds format.
void print_vector(vector<double>converted_time){

cout << "The time it will take for the plane to reach its desired altitude is: " << endl;
cout << converted_time[0] << " hours, ";
cout << converted_time[1] << " minutes and ";
cout << converted_time[2] << " seconds" << endl;
cout << endl;
}


// This prints the distance over ground travelled and if there was a malfuntion.
void print_result (double V, double D){

// This is for the distance it will travel horizontally in the time it takes to to climb.
cout << "The distance over ground you will travel will be ";
cout << D << " meters, or "<< (D/1000)<< "Km" <<endl;
cout << endl;
}

//This prints the angle and also figures out if the plane should be angled up or down.
void print_angle(double Th, double Alt, bool C){
if (Alt < 0){ cout << "The angle below the horizontal the plane should be pointed is " << Th << "    degrees." << endl;
cout << endl;
}
else if (Alt > 0){ cout << "The angle above the horizontal the plane should be pointed is " << Th   << " degrees."<< endl;
cout << endl;
}
//This will determine if the angle was safe or not.
if (Th > 60){
    cout << "The angle required to reach this altitude with the specified climb rate" << endl;
    cout << "was too great, the pilot attempted the climb and stalled the plane" << endl;
    cout << "resulting in a crash" << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
if (C == true){
    cout << "EMERGENCY! The plane experienced serious problems while ascending," << endl;
    cout << " the pilot has lost control and has crashed!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    if (C == false){ cout << " No problems were experienced while ascending" << endl; }
}

}

//This will get the angle required for the plane to point its nose above horizontal. 
double get_angle(double Alt, double Dis){
double angle_degrees;
double angle = atan(Alt / Dis);
angle_degrees = angle*(180 / 3.14159);
return angle_degrees;
}


//Random number generator
int didCrash(double chanceOfCrash) {
    // Add 0-10,000 in 100 loops to get 0-1,000,000

    double val = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        val += (double)((rand() % 10001));
    }

        // Divide by 10,000 to get 0.0000-100.0000
        //  and decide whether crashing or not.

        val /= 10000;

    return (val < chanceOfCrash);
}






// function starts here.
int main(){
double A;
double R;
double T;
double V;
double D;
double Theta;
int rand;
R = RoC();
A = altitude();
T = time(A, R);
vector<double> foo = converted_time(T);

double hours = foo[0]; 
double minutes = foo[1];
double seconds = foo[2];



V = speed();
D = distancetravelled(T,V);

rand = didCrash(D);
bool crash;
if (rand == 1){ crash = true; };
if (rand != 1){ crash = false; };

Theta = get_angle(A, D);
//Note: the print results do not print ONLY what their names are. this is meerly the first thing   they print.
print_result(V, D);
print_vector(foo);
print_angle(Theta, A, crash);







return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `return` is inside your `while` so it will always execute precisely one loop.

Comment: `if (rand = 1)` is always true, this assigns `1` to `rand`. Use `==` as such `if (rand == 1)`

Comment: @Cal, when you change the very nature of your question (such as modifying the code to fix your problems by moving the return outside of the loop), it breaks the entire Q&A concept. The right thing to do in that case is to ask a _different_ question, because the question is fundamentally different. Or, provide an addendum: I'll show you how it's done.

Comment: Clearly i am very confused right now. ive been working on this code for almost 12 hours straight and i am very much a beginner programmer, i really dont know what i am doing. i will update my code to what i have exactly right now. please just fix it for me

Comment: @CalElliott, sorry, got called away. I've boiled your question down to the bare minimum needed and updated my answer. Suggest you check it out.

Comment: Be aware that `rand()` returns values ranging from `0` to `RAND_MAX`; The C Standard mandates only a value of `RAND_MAX` of at least `32767`.

Comment: Cal, on your latest edit, fixed how exactly. The problem has been identified to incorrect `if` statement. What else is the problem? There's little point looking through a hundred lines of code looking for problems which may or may not exist. You need to specify the actual problem and, if it's not the same as the original problem (always seeming to indicate crash), ask a **new** question.

Comment: I would ask a new question and i apologize for being confusing, i am new to this site and it currently will not let me ask any more questions. the code i have put up above still will only display the  crash variable as true, which means the random number generator is only generating 1 as its answer. i need to to only generate 1 occasionally, so crash=false is the far more common answer. i really am sorry, i have very little knowledge on what i am doing. your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cal, work out what value D has when you pass it in to see if it's causing you any problems. But I still have to say you're better off with tried and tested code: lets say D in km. Work out the chance of crashing per km, multiply that by D and pass that to one of the functions in my answer.

Comment: Okay i just had an Epiphany and i totally get what you are saying, sorry, ive only be programming a month now and, your answer worked perfectly, thanks a million. you really saved my behind there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x = rand() % 1000000000000 + 1;
return x;
```

The vast majority of numbers out of that snippet will be non-zero, hence considered true. In fact, possibly *all* of them, given that you're adding one and your almost-certainly-overflowing large number would prevent wraparound to zero.

If you want to return a truth value indicating crash, based on a percentage input, you can use something like:

```
int didCrash (int chanceOfCrash) {
    return ((rand() % 101) < chanceOfCrash);
}
```

It's not *perfectly* distributed but should be good enough for your purposes.

And, if a integral failure rate is not good enough, you could adapt it for more resolution with something like:

```
int didCrash (double chanceOfCrash) {
    // Add 0-10,000 in 100 loops to get 0-1,000,000

    double val = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        val += (double)((rand() % 10001)

    // Divide by 10,000 to get 0.0000-100.0000
    //  and decide whether crashing or not.

    v /= 10000;

    return (val < chanceOfCrash);
}
```

This allows you to specify a resolution down to `0.0001` for very fine crash control.

---

With regard to your edit where you added the calling code:

```
rand = crash_chance(D);
bool crash;
if (rand = 1){ crash = true; };
if (rand != 1){ crash = false; };
```

you have fallen for a "dark corner" trick of the C language.

The statement:

```
if (rand = 1){ crash = true; };
```

has an *assignment* rather than a comparison in it. What it will do is set `rand` to `1` then use that as the basis of the `if` statement.

And, since `1` is true, you will *always* assume a crash.

The correct statement to use would have been:

```
if (rand == 1){ crash = true; };
//       ^^
//       Comparison rather than assignment.
```

However, I *still* think it's a better idea to use one of the `didCrash()` functions contained here since it makes the intent clearer and there's less chance of making a mistake loke this.

Comment: I actually have Boolean variables set so if the random number ever = 1 it sets crash to true, but if it never ends of = 1 then its set to false (see new code above).

Comment: okay i put up what i have now but it still always comes back as true.

Comment: @CalElliott. `if (rand = 1)` is always true, this assigns 1 to rand. Use `==` as such `if (rand == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

rand number returns integer and your range is out of integer. Integer is of 4 bytes and range is between -2,147,483,648 - 2,147,483,647